# SQL Join ON clause valid referencing on aliases

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am generating an SQL query and I need to get the data from a `JSON` stored on a field of my table. It goes something like this

```
SELECT creation.INSERT_DATE as applicationDateTime,
REPLACE(json_extract(creation.FACILITY_DATA, '$.loanType'), '"', '') AS loanType,
lookup_detail.DETAIL_DESCRIPTION AS financingType 
FROM creation 
LEFT JOIN lookup_detail ON lookup_detail.DETAIL_CODE = loanType
```

So basically I am trying to get put a connection with tables **creation** and **lookup_detail** through field ***FACILITY_DATA*** which has `JSON` data and alias of ***loanType*** to reference against ***DETAIL_CODE*** field. However, I get this error

```
code:"ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR"
errno:1054
sqlMessage:"Unknown column 'loanType' in 'on clause'"
sqlState:"42S22"
```

Is there anything I could do to work on this? I tried to search what are the valid reference to `ON` clause of `JOIN` operation, but I only get the typical ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either repeat the expression in the `ON` clause, or join with a subquery.

```
SELECT c.applicationDateTime, c.loanType, l.financingType
FROM (
    SELECT INSERT_DATE as applicationDateTime,
            REPLACE(json_extract(creation.FACILITY_DATA, '$.loanType'), '"', '') AS loanType
    FROM creation
) AS c
JOIN lookup_detail AS l ON l.DETAIL_CODE = c.loanType
```

Also, you probably should be using `JSON_UNQUOTE()` rather than `REPLACE()`. Or you can use the `->>` operator, which extracts and unquotes in one step.

Comment: Barmar, so basically I cannot reference it through `alias`? Can you provide any explanation for that so I can understand what could possible wrong with that way. Also thanks for the great tip for the `JSON_UNQUOTE` and `->>`

Comment: Aliases are part of the result set, which isn't created until after the join.

Comment: It's counter-intuitive for some developers, because the SELECT clause is written above the FROM/JOIN clauses. But the expressions in the select-list, and their aliases, are not evaluated until after the joins and WHERE conditions have filtered out rows. If SQL were evaluated in the order of its syntax, the order of clauses should be `FROM-JOIN-WHERE-SELECT-GROUP BY-HAVING-ORDER BY`